# After upgrade magento 2.4.4 version order shipment is not working?

Tags: magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.4, magento2.4.0, magento2.3.7

i have upgrade magento 2.4.4 version,after upgrade shipment will not create on chrome browser.if i am trying to mozila firefox it's working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA4Y7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYyuu.png

i have also tried to run grep command but that function is not found in our magento directory.

Comment: Have you tried debugging whether the submitShipment required JS source files are downloading in the network tab or not ? And if they are downloading with a HTTP error  code please do share it and compare thee same with the chrome and firefox browser , please try disabling cache in the browser's dev tools by checking that option and keeping the tool open and try the scenario again? Please do share your findings , Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this grep command to find the `submitShipment` function in your project: `grep -r submitShipment <your project path`. If your project path is ~/Sites/magento244, the command will be: `grep -r submitShipment ~/Sites/magento244`.

You will see 2 files that contain the `submitShipment` word:

- vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtml
- vendor/magento/module-shipping/Block/Adminhtml/Create/Items.php

The file declare the `submitShipment` function is vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtml

Try to remove the `vendor` folder and run the following commands, then check if your issues were resolved or not:

```
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

You may need to re-generate static content by command: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`